# Selenium webdriver .click() method fails with chrome browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, xpath, click, webdriver

I am trying click a link using selenium webdriver in Chrome browser but it fails where as its working fine in Firefox.
My chrome version is 35.xx and I have my browser pop-ups unblocked.

**Please find my code below which is working fine in firefox**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Forgot Password?')]")).click();
```

**Please find the html code below**

```
<p class="text-center">
<a href="_____________">Forgot Password?</a>
```

**The below is the error message displayed after the script fail**

> no such element (Session info: chrome=35.0.1916.153) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds

other methods like `.getText()` are working fine.

When i use the below code :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Forgot Password?')]")).getText());
```

..the output is as expected.

Please help me out of this!!

Comment: Have you tried with using other selectors like by text, by tag.. ?

Comment: Hi, yeah i have tried using text selector and it didn't work :(

Comment: try `new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your xpath"));`  and if it doesn't work share HTML or website URL.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try use implicity wait on webDriver init? Like a:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```